# I have two app icons in Recent Applications , how to avoid?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have two activities in "Recent Applications". For those that don't know, Recent Applications is when you long press the home button.

I know why this happens. I am starting my app from a BroadCastIntentReceiver. Then I start my app from the normal launcher icon.

When I press the first icon in Recent Applications, the app opens from the Main activity. However, when I press the second icon, the app opens from the place where the BroadCastIntentReceiver starts the app, this is called PictureActivity.

I have been looking into taskAffinity and am having trouble deciding the most simple way to solve this issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your BroadCastIntentReceiver builds its intent to launch the PictureActivity, try setting this flag on the intent:

```
intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS );
```

Reference: [Android dev site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS).

Comment: Excellent Answer! You will go far in the realm of StackOverflow ;) I am but a hobbling student standing on the shoulders of giants!